# Magento 2 : How to find out store codes using front-end website only?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, store-view

I would like to find out the different ways how one can identify store views if website having multi store codes.

PS. I'm using store switcher at the moment but is there any other way Magento exposing the store codes on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct( ..., \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager ) 
{ 
      
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
}


private function getStoreData()
{          $storeManagerDataList =  $this->_storeManager->getStores();      
    $options = array();           
    foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) 
    {                
        $options[] = ['label' => $value['name'].' - '.$value['code'], 'value' => $key];      
    }      
    return $options; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i don't have access to admin or code. I have only website front name only.

Comment: you don't need any admin access.